# mbstring.language is set to Japanese?

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I'm on an English language server hosted in Australia from Digital Pacific when I was having a look through my PHP.ini file in WHM I saw that the mbstring.language is set to Japanese. Will this effect anything in a negative way or is it best to leave it as it is?

The mbstring.internal_encoding is also set to EUC-JP

I'm having some issues with some plugins on one of my WordPress sites so might this be effecting it?

Cheers

Comment: So you think I should change it to English? Just wanted to make sure it wouldn't crash anything already installed on the server before I did.

Comment: crazy idea, ask the host, who set this up.

Comment: It's a rented dedicated server from Digital Pacific, as it's unmanaged, they charge $100 an hour to look at any issue, I'd rather not have to pay that. This is how the server came from them. Plus although I have full admin access, it's not me who rants it from them. And the person who does, isn't currently available to message them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to check if you could overwrite this setting with `.htaccss` or PHP functions such as `mb_language()` and `ini_set()` .

The value of mb_language is used for encoding e-mail messages. mb_send_mail() uses this setting to encode e-mail. So, it is good to set "English" or "uni"(UTF-8) unless you use Japanse character sets.

**Set with .htaccess**

> When using PHP as an Apache module, you can also change the
>   configuration settings using directives in Apache configuration files
>   (e.g. httpd.conf) and .htaccess files. You will need "AllowOverride
>   Options" or "AllowOverride All" privileges to do so.

```
#
#  .htaccess
#
php_value date.timezone "America/Los_Angeles"
php_value default_charset "UTF-8"
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"
```

The document is here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

**Set with PHP functions**

```
<?php
  mb_language('English');
  ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
  mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
?>
```

You can see documnets here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-language.php